# Comparing two columns in one table

Tags: php, mysql

I have one table like this:

```
+---------+----------+
| column1 |  column2 |
+---------+----------+
|   100   |    50    |
|    3    |    10    |          
|    7    |     7    |
+---------+----------+
```

I would like a SQL statement which compares the data between `column1` and `column2`, counting the number of rows for which `column1` has a value smaller than that in `column2`.

Perhaps something like:

```
$result="select * from table where column1 <= column2";
$a = mysql_num_rows ($result);
echo $a;
```

In this example, it would give me a result of `2`, representing the matching rows #2 and #3.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT count(*)  AS total_rows  
FROM table_with_data   
WHERE column1 <= column2
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try just running that query? It seems to me that it would give the answer you seek.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column1` <= `column2`");
echo mysql_num_rows($result);
```

However, it would be more efficient to retrieve the count from MySQL, rather than retrieving *all the data* from MySQL then counting it after-the-fact:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `n` FROM `table` WHERE `column1` <= `column2`");
$row    = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row[0];
```